# The form did't send the data to the back end in Django customize form

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to customize the **ModelMultipleChoiceField** in the form but when I am trying to submit the form I get error **Enter a list of values**.

forms.py:

```
class AppointmentCreateViewForm(forms.ModelForm):
    patient= forms.ModelChoiceField( queryset=Patient.objects.all(),label="Patient")
    appointmentDate = forms.DateField(label="Appointment date", widget=forms.DateInput(format='%Y-%m-%d'))
    appointmentType = forms.ChoiceField(choices=AppointmentTypes, required=False, label="Appointmen type")
    appointmentStatus = forms.ChoiceField(label="Appointment Status", choices=AppointmentStatuss)
    operation = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(widget=forms.Select(attrs={
                'class': 'js-example-basic-multiple',
                'name': 'states[]',
                'multiple': 'multiple'
            }), queryset=Operation.objects.all(),label="Operation")
    class Meta:
        model = Appointment
        fields = ('patient', 'appointmentDate', 'appointmentType','appointmentStatus','operation')
```

Html file:

```
<section>
     <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
         {{ form.as_p }}  
         <input type="submit" value="Save" />
        </form>
    </section>
```

models.py:

```
class Operation(models.Model):
    operationName = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.operationName

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('operations')
```

Comment: Well, [`ModelMultipleChoiceField`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/forms/fields/#django.forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField) default widget is `SelectMultiple`. Also share `Appointment` model, does the `operation` is ManyToManyField?

Comment: I shared the Appointment model

Comment: no the operation is operationName = models.CharField(max_length=255) in the operation model

Comment: can you add also the print(request.POST) resullt und django error trace?